# Why Image is not Shown in cellforRowAtIndexPath in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, uitableview, uiimageview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to show image in the Image View from Web Service.I am using code like this

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *STI=@"STI";
    NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    NSString *strImgURLAsString = [NewsImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            if (img==nil) {
               // img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"userimage.png"];
            }
            cell.newsimage.image=img;

            // pass the img to your imageview
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }
    }];

    cell.Headlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[headarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *aux = [shortnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body>";
    NSString *htmlString2=@"</body></html>";
    NSString * NewString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",htmlString,aux,htmlString2];

    NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[NewString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    cell.bodylbl.attributedText=attrStr;
    cell.bodylbl.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    cell.bodylbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.bodylbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];

    cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;


   // cell.bodylbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shortnamearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 //   cell.randrid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;

}
```

Image Path - http://qaec.teams.in.net/UploadedFiles/Tommy Schaefer, of his role in the slaying, for which he is serving 18 year.png

```
http://qaec.teams.in.net/UploadedFiles/Tommy%20Schaefer,%20of%20his%20role%20in%20the%20slaying,%20for%20which%20he%20is%20serving%2018%20year.png
```

[image]
When Image Does not contain any gap it shows image 
But when the Image contain any gap it not show image.How to solve this problem.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try set image in main thread:
    `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.newsimage.image=img;
    });`

Comment: please add screen of image which does not display

Comment: @nynohu Not work.

Comment: @Muju try this cell.newsimage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data]]

Comment: @Muju You can also try SDWebImage in which you need to pass url and default image and also first check data length

Comment: try to replace space to blank [strImgURLAsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]

Comment: @Muju check my answer below.

Comment: Check the IBOutlet connection of cell.newsimage.

Comment: Pls post your full code in cellForRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use any other library etc. Your code is mistake on this line:

```
[strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Have a look at this what does it do? Nothing. You should reassign the variable strImgURLAsString to this then it should work:

```
 strImgURLAsString = [strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: No Not Work. Still Not Shown Image.

Comment: Thats weird I just tested in xcode and it works. The image is large so wait a while.

Comment: Not sure why code works in my xcode and not work in yours. That is weird coz I copy your code and modify "strImgURLAsString =" only and it works.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following method in UITableviewCell class. In your case add code in NewsTableViewCell.m When cell is created that time drowRect method is called. So in this method you need to set setClipsToBounds property of image view for which you setting the image to YES. This will solve your issue.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    self.profilePicImgView.layer.cornerRadius=self.profilePicImgView.frame.size.width/2;
    [self.profilePicImgView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [self.profilePicImgView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.profilePicImgView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, you can try this library called SDWebImage.

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qaec.teams.in.net/UploadedFiles/Tommy%20Schaefer,%20of%20his%20role%20in%20the%20slaying,%20for%20which%20he%20is%20serving%2018%20year.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

Also 
You need to make sure that you have written this in your plist file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
       if (!connectionError) {

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            if (img==nil) {
               // img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"userimage.png"];
            }
            cell.newsimage.image=img;

            // pass the img to your imageview
          });
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's good to idea to load image url in Imageview like the way you have written for better understanding of process. But maintaining cache is also important thing to consider. For better performance, I recommend you to use a very good library called [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It helps you out in loading images faster with it's cache mechanism. Try this out. With this library it's this much simple.

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Here is another one.
If you are using AFNetworking in your app, use below code to do that.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    _imageView.image = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
}];
[requestOperation start];
```